# SQL Server : query filter return results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I realize this is might be an unusual request. I'm trying to create a compliance report.

The following query needs to be altered to verify certain returned items. The returned values will be either compliant, non-compliant (displaying the version 3), or missing. I tried using case statement however if the item is missing nothing is returned.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.DisplayName0, 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.Version0
FROM 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.v_R_System ON dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.ResourceID = dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID
WHERE 
    (dbo.v_R_System.Netbios_Name0 LIKE 'isa-lab0277') 
    AND (NOT (dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.Version0 = 'NULL'))
ORDER BY 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.DisplayName0
```

Logic

- If X = Y then mark compliant, if Y is missing mark it missing and not compliant, if Y is the wrong version return the value and mark it not compliant

Return values for X and Y. Return if the item is compliant or not (X=Y or X != Y)

Example Solution

Logic Requested by Kevin

If X = Y then mark compliant, if Y is missing mark it missing and not compliant, if Y is the wrong version return the value and mark it not compliant

Return values for X and Y.  Return if the item is compliant or not (X=Y or X != Y)

Example solution report

```
STD Software Configuration    System Configuration Items    Status
Active Client 1.0.123     Active Client 1.0.123         Compliant
Adobe Flash Player 10.4.6.1   Adobe Flash Player 10.3.0.1   Not Compliant
Adobe Reader 1.9.123      none                          Missing
```

Comment: Having some example data and a cleaned up version of the example solution would be helpful (I think it should be showing rows of data you expect?). Something on http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be better yet.

Comment: I believe that if you change your query to a left join then you should be able to use your case statement as expected. The inner join will be excluding any results where you want to return missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly testing for a missing value, then you need to change the criteria for a NULL comparison

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.DisplayName0, 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.Version0
FROM 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.v_R_System ON dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.ResourceID = dbo.v_R_System.ResourceID
WHERE 
    (dbo.v_R_System.Netbios_Name0 LIKE 'isa-lab0277') 
    AND (NOT (dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.Version0 IS NULL)) --<<<<<<<<< Look here
ORDER BY 
    dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs.DisplayName0
```